# "This site may be hacked" google result on Wordpress page

Tags: google, google-search, wordpress, search, hacked-site

My problem is that when I search for my site on google (a Wordpress page), it shows the correct web address, but clicking the link redirects to a site selling Windows keys.

However, if I actually type the address into the address bar and visit the site manually, I reach my site correctly. What is the name for this kind of attack? I want to research and fix the problem, but I don't know the terminology, and there seem to be a lot of different ways to compromise a web page.

Also, any recommendations for how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear due to the lack of information provided, answers would be guesses at best. Please edit your question and include things like the contents of your `.htaccess` file as this is the most common cause for redirect hacks. Additionally you should look at the contents of your theme header.php, footer.php and so on. Not all hacks are the same and they vary from one to another, so currently the question is unclear and too broad. Please do some investigation work and narrow down where you think could be the cause.

Comment: Also, sharing the site in question may help you further because people might be kind enough to look at your source code.

Answer (score 1):

The "This site may be hacked" notification won't be removed until the webmaster of the site takes action.

Try these steps to fix your website:

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190597?hl=en

In addition,

go to root directory of your website and delete everything that is not wordpress related.